# Determine click type (right or left) on dynamically created button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hi I have several dynamically created buttons with an AddHandler Event added:

```
AddHandler btn.MouseDown, AddressOf TaskButtonClicked
```

In my TaskButtonClicked event I want to know which mouse button was clicked (left or right)

For this test i'm happy to just get a message box that says what type was clicked i.e.

```
Private Sub TaskButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim clickedButton as xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

    MsgBox(clickedButton)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: This is for Windows Forms

Comment: Then you should be sure to add the [tag:winforms] so that the Windows Forms experts will see it. I've done that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, figured it out on my own.  If anyone cares I had to change the EventArgs type in the handler Sub to MouseEventArgs it works like this...

```
Private Sub TaskButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        MsgBox("Right Click")
    End If

End Sub
```